# Puede alguien crear las etiquetas kubectl, kubernetes y kubeadm?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

## ¿Por qué se require?

Se requiere catalogar las preguntas relacionadas con Kubernetes.

Kubertes: Orquestador de servicios Cloud del CNF.

Kubectl: Comando usado para manejar un cluster de Kubernetes

Kubeadm:  Comando usado para crear y administrar un cluster de Kubernetes

En la comunidad de español hay poca transferencia de conocimiento de estas tecnologías. Esto se evidenecia en el bajo número de preguntas.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=kubernetes

Considero importante catalogar bien estas preguntas pues es una fuerte tendencia mundial en la nube y en Devops.

Este tipo de etiquetas ya estan creadas en la comunidad anglosajona como en este ejemplo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45096990/kops-kuberntes-instance-group-autoscaling

Y el índice de preguntas al respecto de **kubernetes** supera con creces el de nuestra comunidad:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=kubernetes

```
Busquedas por Kubernetes
Español: 9 
Ingles:  27,472
```

## PREGUNTAS CANDIDATAS A USAR ESTAS ETIQUETAS

[Problema con Deployments en Kubernetes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/172832/problema-con-deployments-en-kubernetes)

[¿Cómo asignar una IP externa en un servicio de k8s?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/203948/c%C3%B3mo-asignar-una-ip-externa-en-un-servicio-de-k8s)

[Replicas en kubernetes entre nodos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/185776/replicas-en-kubernetes-entre-nodos)

## Etiquetas del ecosistema de Kubernetes en Ingles.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Indica alguna pregunta que deba llevarlas, pues una etiqueta se crea al añadirla a una pregunta

Comment: La comunidad en español esta iniciando a preguntar de estas tecnologías https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=kubernetes

Comment: Claro, espléndida iniciativa. Pero ya que eres ducho en el tema, señala alguna pregunta que deba usar estas etiquetas para que se la añadamos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que es buena idea tener [kubernetes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes) pero las otras dos no tanto en particular porque se trata de comandos no deberían crearse etiquetas por cada comando que pueda tener una plataforma o lenguaje.

Comment: En ingles existen todas esas etiquetas, pero si, la mayor cantidad de preguntas se hacen con Kubernetes e inclusive tiene Icono. Podemos ponerle Icono?

Comment: El sitio en inglés tiene más tiempo una cantidad enorme de preguntas así como de usuarios y no necesariamente todo lo que allá pasa es "ejemplar". En cuanto al ícono ese se muestra allá porque es una etiqueta patrocinada. [es.so] aún no tiene etiquetas patrocinadas. Supongo que para que tengamos etiquetas patrocinadas primero deberá haber alguien interesado en patrocinar alguna etiqueta.

Comment: Por cierto, [tag:kubernetes] ya ha sido creada.

Comment: Muchas gracias Rubén